# What is the Dirac mass on measure space?

Tags: measure-theory, integration, random-variables, mathematical-physics

I am reading the book "Lectures on Stochastic Analysis." But I know seldom about measure space. I meet with a symbol which the author call **Dirac mass**(in 9.3 of this book). Let E be a measurable space,  $x\in E$, $\delta_{x}$ is the Dirac mass at x. So what is **Dirac mass** on a measurable space.

Comment: It's probably a synonym for the Dirac _measure_ $\delta_x$ which is a probability measure defined by $\delta_x(A)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\delta_x(A)=0$ if $x\not\in A$.

Comment: Yeah, it is the Dirac measure. Thanks Stefan Hansen.